# Syntax error in ArrayList

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I am trying to add an element to my arraylist of class 'Pallet'. Here is what I did:

```
ArrayList<Pallet> pallets = new ArrayList<Pallet>();
    pallets.add(Pallet lightsabers = new Pallet(cargoType.LIGHT_SABERS));
```

However, I now get a syntax error on both parentheses surrounding the `Pallet lightsabers = ....  _SABERS)` part. The one for the left parenthesis is

> Syntax error on token "(", . expected" and the one for the right is "Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

I do not know where I went wrong and I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: The answer below shows a valid syntax but there is nothing random about the syntax error.  It is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this

```
pallets.add(new Pallet(cargoType.LIGHT_SABERS));
```

---

if you want the `lightsabers` variable(it doesn't look like you need one), you can do this

```
Pallet lightsabers = new Pallet(cargoType.LIGHT_SABERS);
pallets.add(lightsabers);
```

Comment: I now get different errors. I get:                                  >Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
 - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
 - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
  MethodHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName, im really sorry about the mess of this text, i dont quite understand the formatting yet.

Comment: @Pim it sounds like you have a number of syntax errors throughout your project.  What you should do is to just build a small portion of it at a time, and then compile and/or run.  That way you only have to deal with a few errors at a time rather than all at once

Comment: I have the Pallet class ready, as well as an enum cargoType, so I thought this should work. I'll move on and maybe it will resolve itself later. Thanks though!

Comment: It was resolved by putting the add method inside another method, any idea why this happened? Maybe because it needs all the standard 10 slots to fill up?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create a variable, you just need an instance of Pallet.

```
pallets.add(new Pallet(cargoType.LIGHT_SABERS));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a new Pallet object to a variable inside your method call.

it should be `pallets.add(new Pallet(cargoType.LIGHT_SABERS))`